# "No module named gdbm" error when running Python program from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a simple python3 program that uses the shelve module from the Ubuntu terminal and I keep getting this error. I've tried removing and re-installing the python-gdbm package to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: Check if there is python3-gdbm or install using pip.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mcb.pyw", line 11, in <module>
    mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb', 'w')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 243, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 84, in open
    mod = __import__(result)
ImportError: No module named gdbm